# phpMyAdmin doesn't work when installing from repo

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've just installed phpMyAdmin via apt-get and rebooted. When i enter '127.0.0.1:3306' into web browser, i get something like this:

[image]

I'm totally new to mysql but quite experienced with linux.

How could i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access the mysql port instead of accessing phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin runs on port 80, so there is no reason to specify a port in the web address bar.

Try going here:
127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

That should load up the web interface you are looking for.

Comment: 404. not found :(

Comment: Ok, just to clarify. 3306 is the Mysql port. This is not what you want. This is why your response looks so funny. The default phpmyadmin from apt-get would be accessed at that location. First step, verify you have phpmyadmin installed by typing `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`. If it was already installed, open a terminal and verify that you have the file: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: i dont have phpmyadmin.conf. where do i get it?

Comment: Have you verified that phpmyadmin is installed? Run this command: `sudo apt-get purgephpmyadmin` then run `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.  Ubuntu's official repositories do place the config file. So you either do not have phpmyadmin installed, or you are working with something not Ubuntu related. If this does not work, please comment which instructions you used to install phpmyadmin.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` - this is the command i executed. I've just now downloaded bundled phpmyadmin and placed it in my target folder. works pretty well. i thing the question is closed now.